# JMH AnnotationProcessor NullPointerException

Tags: java, jmh

I created maven archetype project as specified in the JMH homepage.
I am getting "Annotation generator had thrown the exception. java.lang.NullPointerException"
when I do maven build of the generated project.
My java file is

```
    public class MyBenchMark
     //   extends Benchmark
{
    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void timeMyOperation(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
          //  ConcurrentHashMapTest.populateConcurrenctHashMap();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws RunnerException {
        MyBenchMark myBenchMark = new MyBenchMark();
     //   myBenchMark.timeMyOperation(50);


        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(".*" + MyBenchMark.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
                .forks(1)
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

}
```

`.
The exception I get is

```
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project perftest: Compilation failure
error: Annotation generator had thrown the exception. java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
error: Annotation generator had thrown the exception. java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:745)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int reps` is what trips JMH. As per `GenerateMicroBenchmark` Javadoc: 
"The arguments should be zero or more State-bearing classes. See State docs for the exact contract." Drop `int reps` from the arguments, and it should be fine. By the way, what you do with your benchmark is questionable, please read [JMH samples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/) first.

The error message should be better, working on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot.That works.Will surely look for the correct usage of benchmarks.